# Bouyancy and Floating

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, buoyancy

When an object is floating, which means a part of it is in water and another part in air. In this case is the bouyant force greater than weight because my intuition says that if Buoyant force was not greater that the weight rather it was equal the object would have just remained below the surface of water and would be in equilibrium. So in which case the object will float, and if the first case is called floating then what is the second case called or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When an object is floating, which means a part of it is in water and
>   another part in air.

Part of the object does not have to be partially in the air in order for the object to be "floating". All that is required is the upward buoyant force acting on the object equals the downward weight of the object. That occurs when the weight of the volume of water displaced by the submerged portion of the object equals the weight of the object.

> In this case is the bouyant force greater than weight

No. If the buoyant force is greater than the weight, the object will move upward until the volume of the water displaced by the submerged portion of the object equals the weight of the object. That is, when the buoyant force equals the weight.

> because my intuition says that if Buoyant force was not greater that
>   the weight rather it was equal the object would have just remained
>   below the surface of water and would be in equilibrium.

If the buoyant force equals the weight of the object it will float. This applies whether the object is completely submerged or partially submerged because the buoyant force is different. It is the density of the object compared to that of the water surrounding it that determines how much of the body is submerged. If the density of the object is less than the water, it will float partially submerged. If it is equal, it will float completely below the surface of the water. If it is greater than the water, it will sink until, and unless, the water density increases to equal the density of the object.

Hope this helps.